# SellectCommad.connection Property not initialized

Tags: c#, asp.net

When i debug my application, it gives an error that SelectCommand.Connection Property is not been initialized. i dont know what am i doing here wrong :s. I actually want to add a filter over my search on the textchanged event of a textbox.

```
public class ConnectionClass
{
    static SqlConnection cn;

    public static SqlConnection Connection()
    {
        string myConnection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["_uniManagementConnectionString1"].ConnectionString;
        if (cn != null)
        {
            cn = new SqlConnection(myConnection);
            cn.Open();
        }
        return cn;
    }

}    

public class ClassDataManagement 
{ 
    SqlConnection cn = ConnectionClass.Connection();

    public DataTable GetData(string SQL)
    {
         SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SQL, cn);
         SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
         DataTable dt = new DataTable();
         da.Fill(dt);
         return dt;
    } 
}

protected void TextBoxFilterText_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ClassDataManagement dm = new ClassDataManagement();
   string query = "Select CourseCode from _Courses where coursecode like'%" + TextBoxFilterText.Text.TrimEnd() + "%'";
   dm.GetData(query);
   GridViewCourses.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: You have a SQL-Injection vulnerability, use Parameters. Apart from that you're never closing the connection what might result in an "too many connections" exception but certainly will decrease performance. It is better not to store the connection in a static field. Create the connection object on demand and let the connection pooling manage your connections. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx

Comment: Tim what about if the OP puts that sql code in a .config file

Comment: @DJ Kraze: Sorry, I don't quite follow. The problem is not the Connection-String but this class as a whole. A (static) global connection class is one of the no-go's in ADO.NET, all the more if you're not using SqlParameters, not creating,opening,using,closing Connections in short order and more than ever in a multi-threaded environment(like ASP.NET).

Comment: @TimSchmelter: I think DJ Kraze's comment forgot the /sarcasm tag. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because your `cn` variable is `null`, and not getting initialized.  Yet another example why it's a bad idea to initialize and open database connections in a static method.

Try this:

```
public class ClassDataManagement 
{ 
   public DataTable GetData(string SQL)
    {
          string YourConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["_uniManagementConnectionString1"].ConnectionString;     
          DataTable dt = new DataTable();             

          using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(YourConnectionString))
          using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SQL, cn))
          using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
          {
              da.Fill(dt);
          }
          return dt;
    } 
}
```

With the `SqlDataAdapter` class, you don't need to explicitly call `SqlConnection.Open()`.  The `SqlDataAdapter.Fill()` method handles all of the connection opening (and closing).

[MSDN Reference on `SqlDataAdapter.Fill()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/905keexk.aspx)

As per the above reference, quoted:

> The connection object associated with the SELECT statement must be valid, but it does not need to be open. If the connection is closed before Fill is called, it is opened to retrieve data, then closed. If the connection is open before Fill is called, it remains open.

Comment: Shark could have wrapped a using around that as well to dispose of the connection but that's a matter of style

Comment: @DJKRAZE I believe `SqlDataAdapter.Fill()` handles the disposing of the connection.

Comment: humm I will have to check on that.. not doubting you but actually curious myself..

Comment: This is what the msdn site says This implementation of the SqlDataAdapter opens and closes a SqlConnection if it is not already open. This can be useful in an application that must call the Fill method for two or more SqlDataAdapter objects. If the SqlConnection is already open, you must explicitly call Close or Dispose to close it. When an instance of SqlDataAdapter is created, the following read/write properties are set to the following initial values.   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kx703tc9.aspx

Comment: This still has the possibility of leaking connections.  If the query fails (excepts out) then the connection and command objects will be left hanging out there.  Unlike what DJ KRAZE said, it's not a matter of style, it's actually a matter of writing better code.

Comment: @DJKRAZE Right, exactly.  That's why I let the DataAdapter handle the connection.

Comment: if it remains open then you would still need to dispose() of it is how I am reading it.. I saw something similar on StackOverFlow as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469459/does-sqldataadapter-dispose-actually-close-an-associated-sqlconnection

Comment: @ChrisLively Noted, I have modified my code to put the connection in a `using` block so that `Dispose()` is explicitly called.

Comment: I understand completely @Shark.. I also understand that that's not always a guaranteed thing as well but I Voted up on your answer as well also wrapping a using(){} wouldn't hurt it either.. just I am so use to using the using ...pardon the pun.. lol

Comment: no hard feeling @Shark  we all learn something new everyday.. have a good one...It's Miller Time = BEER :)

Comment: @Shark: Not to harp on a point, but that only takes care of the SqlConnection.  Both SqlCommand and SqlDataAdapter also implement IDisposable as they are handling unmanaged objects.  They should be included in their own using clauses to ensure those resources are also cleaned up.  See sebastians answer below

Comment: I would do one of the two using(){} or if (cmd != null)((IDisposable)cmd).Dispose(); same for SqlDataAdapter...

Comment: there's only 1 issue with this code....variable dt is declared within using and therefore will not be available for the return statement.

Answer (score 3):

Open connection and close as soon as possible.

```
    public DataTable GetData(string commandString)
    {
        var result = new DataTable();

        using (var cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["_uniManagementConnectionString1"].ConnectionString))
            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(commandString, cn))
                using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    da.Fill(result);
                }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: +1 for the only decent answer here that addresses at least most of the issues.

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't that be

```
if (cn == null)
{
    cn = new SqlConnection(myConnection);
    cn.Open();
}
```

Comment: No.. Look at @Sharks example it should be in a Public Method not a Static.. the answer is a good check but his example is even better.. I am not knocking your answere antar125.. just appears that the OP is creating his own Custom Connection Class / Data Connector Class..

Comment: @DJKRAZE just saw it. Thanks!

Comment: It will fix OP's problem.  The static class is a bad idea here but it will work.

Comment: I agree but it will work but based on the OP's initial code the refactored suggestion looks cleaner and it's reusable as well in my opinion

Comment: @DJKRAZE, like you have mentioned in previous answer's comment, I would have also used a using statement or tyr-catch-finally block just to make sure it properly handles if there's any exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

Although Sebastian's answer covers a good portion of what's wrong.  Here is a more complete list.

1. You have SQL Injection issues.  All queries should be parameterized otherwise you are asking for trouble.  Especially when you are directly appending text entered by the user.
2. You are leaking resources: `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand`.  These need to be as close to the code that actually utilizes the connection and command as possible.  Trust me, Windows is more than capable of handling all of the open/closing of connections through the build in connection pool.  You don't need to maintain this yourself.
3. The code itself is brittle due to use of embedded SQL in your display layer.  By way of example, let's say `CourseCode` is renamed to `CourseId`.  You will have to search through and modify, potentially, a lot of code files just to make that change.  There are multiple ways of limiting exposure to this issue; I'll leave that for you to research.

If I ran across this code in the wild, I would delete the `ConnectionClass` in its entirety.  There is nothing that it is going to do for your that shouldn't be done elsewhere in a more robust manner.

Next I would delete the `GetData()` method.  That is just bad code.  You should never accept a full sql string and blindly execute it.  There are a lot of security issues just in that one block of code.

Then I would rewrite the ClassDataManagement such that my SQL (if I really wanted it to stay embedded, which I wouldn't because I don't roll that way) was the container for all of my queries.  I would have good methods like `GetCourseByCourseCode(String courseCode)` which would validate that the courseCode is in an expected format then pass it to my sqlcommand object as a parameter to the query.

For bonus points I'd expand on the above by looking at what calls could be better served by cached data.  By having them in identified methods, it's much easier to pick and choose what can come from the cache vs what I really need to go across the network and run a query for.

Next, I would make sure that everywhere I made a SQL call, I had my SqlConnection, SqlCommand and readers wrapped in using clauses.  It's the best way to ensure that everything is properly closed and disposed of prior to leaving the method.  Anything less and you are inviting trouble.

Finally, I would highly consider using Enterprise Library for my data access.  It's much better.

Answer (score 0):

Having all given advices, to solve your current problem, you may try this way also:

```
 public class ConnectionClass
 {
 static SqlConnection cn;

   public static SqlConnection Connection()
    {
       string myConnection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["_uniManagementConnectionString1"].ConnectionString;

       return new SqlConnection(myConnection);
      }
   }    

public class ClassDataManagement 
{       
 public DataTable GetData(string SQL)
   {
    using (SqlConnection cn = ConnectionClass.Connection())
     {
     //SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SQL, cn);
     SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(SQL,cn);
     DataTable dt = new DataTable();
     da.Fill(dt);
     return dt;
     }
   } 
......
```

Comment: nuux, and where are you getting the cn i.e connection string.. you should put the full related code in there as well otherwise some other user on this site may see that answer as a solution..

Comment: not a problem just don't want someone to downvote your response.

Answer (score 0):

```
public DataTable GetData()
{
    using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("YourConnection string"))
    {
        con.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            string expression = "Parameter value";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "Your Stored Procedure";
            cmd.Parameters.Add("Your Parameter Name",
                        SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = expression;
            cmd.Connection = con;
            using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(SQL, cn))
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);
                return dt;
            }
        }
    }
}
```